# Microsoft Azure Single Page Application CORS error

Tags: azure, cors

I am building a single page application (spa) that retrieves an access token using the [OAuth2 authorization code flow](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow). The application successfully makes the initial request to Microsoft (`login.microsoftonline.com/consumers/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`), which returns the loing popup code for my application to display. I try entering in an email address (any address, even a valid one) and the request is blocked by CORS.

[image: login popup]
The network inspect tool shows this:
[image: network results]
The details look like this:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://login.live.com/GetCredentialType.srf?
    opid=XXX&id=123456&client_id=XXX&client_id=1a1a1a1a-1a1a-1111-1a1a-1a1a1a1a1a1a&
    mkt=EN-US&lc=1033&uaid=1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a'
    from origin 'http://localhost:3000'
    has been blocked by CORS policy:
    Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check:
    No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

In the Azure application registration setup I have added `http://localhost:3000/` as a redirect URI. However, the login process is not even getting to the redirect step. The login popup is calling out to `login.live.com` and the origin is being blocked. The request is originating from the same application, also located at `http://localhost:3000/`.

I am wondering if I have missed a step. The "Integration assistant" claims that my application has been configured properly.

How do I get past this CORS error?

---

I am not setting any explicit headers for the initial request.

Initial Request:

```
GET /consumers/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
    client_id=1a1a1a1a-1a1a-1111-1a1a-1a1a1a1a1a1a
    &code_challenge=YwMZWMzYTUZGjFiYjJA5mZMGFmNjc2MDZiZDVijkwOD
    &code_challenge_method=S256
    &redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2F
    &response_mode=query
    &response_type=code
    &scope=XboxLive.signin+Xboxlive.offline_access
    &state=test HTTP/1.1
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
User-Agent: Go-http-client/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip
```

Initial Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-store, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Sat, 25 Mar 2023 15:31:52 GMT
Expires: Sat, 25 Mar 2023 15:30:53 GMT
Link: <https://logincdn.msauth.net>; rel=preconnect; crossorigin
Link: <https://acctcdn.msauth.net>; rel=preconnect; crossorigin
Link: <https://acctcdn.msftauth.net>; rel=preconnect; crossorigin
Link: <https://acctcdn.msauth.net/>; rel=dns-prefetch
Link: <https://acctcdn.msftauth.net/>; rel=dns-prefetch
Link: <https://acctcdnmsftuswe2.azureedge.net/>; rel=dns-prefetch
Link: <https://acctcdnvzeuno.azureedge.net/>; rel=dns-prefetch
Link: <https://logincdn.msauth.net/>; rel=dns-prefetch
Link: <https://logincdn.msftauth.net/>; rel=dns-prefetch
Link: <https://lgincdnvzeuno.azureedge.net/>; rel=dns-prefetch
Link: <https://lgincdnmsftuswe2.azureedge.net/>; rel=dns-prefetch
P3p: CP=\"DSP CUR OTPi IND OTRi ONL FIN\"
Ppserver: PPV: 30 H: BL02PFD37B79816 V: 0
Referrer-Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Set-Cookie: MSPRequ=id=N&lt=1679758313&co=1; domain=login.live.com; Secure; path=/; SameSite=None; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: uaid=a9810b4acab94588828d21a75a3dd8d0; domain=login.live.com; Secure; path=/; SameSite=None; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: MSCC=136.36.179.9-US; expires=Thu, 18-Apr-2024 15:31:53 GMT; domain=login.live.com; Secure; path=/; SameSite=None; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: MSPOK=$uuid-00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000; domain=login.live.com; Secure; path=/; SameSite=None; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: OParams=11O.***snip***; domain=login.live.com; Secure; path=/; SameSite=None; HttpOnly
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Dns-Prefetch-Control: on
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Ms-Request-Id: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
X-Ms-Route-Info: R3_BL2
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block

<!-- Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. --><!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- ServerInfo: BL02PFD37B79816 2023.03.14.19.17.04 LocVer:0 -->
<!-- PreprocessInfo: CBA-0314_190146:SA2PNPF0000238B, 2023-03-14T19:13:20.7561491-07:00 - Version: 16,0,29745,6 -->
<!-- RequestLCID: 1033, Market:EN-US, PrefCountry: US, LangLCID: 1033, LangISO: EN -->
<html dir=\"ltr\" lang=\"EN-US\"><head>
---SNIP---
<script type=\"text/javascript\">window.WhenAllLoaded = function (callback)
{ window.$DepLoader.WhenLoaded(window.UXResourceDependencies, callback); };
</script>
</head><body class=\"cb\" data-bind=\"defineGlobals: ServerData, bodyCssClass\">
</body></html>
```

---

Comment: Can you provide the code that you used ?

Comment: I am not sure what part of the code would be useful to show here. I have updated the question with a dump of the initial request and response. It seems like there might just be a setting at Azure that I have missed to help with CORS.